# Multi-level Python Dict to Pandas DataFrame only processes one level out of many

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I'm parsing some XML data, doing some logic on it, and trying to display the results in an HTML table. The dictionary, after filling, looks like this:

```
{
  "general_info": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "description": "xxx",
    "language": "xxx",
    "prefix": "xxx",
    "version": "xxx"
  },
  "element_count": {
    "folders": 23,
    "conditions": 72,
    "listeners": 1,
    "outputs": 47
  },
  "external_resource_count": {
    "total": 9,
    "extensions": {
      "jar": 8,
      "json": 1
    },
    "paths": {
      "/lib": 9
    }
  },
  "complexity": {
    "over_1_transition": {
      "number": 4,
      "percentage": 30.769
    },
    "over_1_trigger": {
      "number": 2,
      "percentage": 15.385
    },
    "over_1_output": {
      "number": 4,
      "percentage": 30.769
    }
  }
}
```

Then I'm using pandas to convert the dictionary into a table, like so:

```
data_frame = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(data=extracted_metrics, orient='index').stack().to_frame()
```

The result is a table that is mostly correct:

[image: results table]

While the first and second levels seem to render correctly, those categories with a sub-sub category get written as a string in the cell, rather than as a further column. I've also tried using `stack(level=1)` but it raises an error "IndexError: Too many levels: Index has only 1 level, not 2". I've also tried making it into a series with no luck. It seems like it only renders "complete" columns. Is there a way of filling up the empty spaces in the dictionary before processing?

How can I get, for example, *external_resource_count -> extensions* to have two daughter rows *jar* and *json*, with an additional column for the values, so that the final table looks like this:

[image: wanted_results]

Extra credit if anyone can tell me how to get rid of the first row with the index numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you load the dataframe is correct but you should rename the `0` to a some column name.

```
# this function extracts all the keys from your nested dicts 
def explode_and_filter(df, filterdict):
    return [df[col].apply(lambda x:x.get(k) if type(x)==dict else x).rename(f'{k}') 
            for col,nested in filterdict.items() 
            for k in nested]


data_frame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data= extracted_metrics, orient='index').stack().to_frame(name='somecol')

#lets separate the rows where a dict is present & explode only those rows
mask = data_frame.somecol.apply(lambda x:type(x)==dict)
expp = explode_and_filter(data_frame[mask], 
                      {'somecol':['jar', 'json', '/lib', 'number', 'percentage']})

# here we concat the exploded series to a frame 
exploded_df = pd.concat(expp, axis=1).stack().to_frame(name='somecol2').reset_index(level=2)\.rename(columns={'level_2':'somecol'})

# and now we concat the rows with dict elements with the rows with non dict elements
out = pd.concat([data_frame[~mask], exploded_df])
```

The output dataframe looks like this [image]